# cv::Mat from Gstreamermm BaseTransform

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I wrote a program to test Gst::BaseTransform.
It shows the video well with the red circle. But the red circle is flickering.
It means the red circle is not appearing on all frames.
I think some frames are not properly handled.

In my code, transform_ip_vfunc is handling the frames.

How can I solve this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <gstreamermm.h>
#include <gstreamermm/private/basetransform_p.h>
#include<glibmm/main.h>
#include <vector>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace Gst;
using namespace std;

class DerivedFromBaseTransform : public Gst::BaseTransform
{
public:
  static void class_init(Gst::ElementClass<DerivedFromBaseTransform> *klass) {
    klass->set_metadata("derivedfrombasetransform_longname",
          "derivedfrombasetransform_classification", "derivedfrombasetransform_detail_description", "derivedfrombasetransform_detail_author");

    klass->add_pad_template(Gst::PadTemplate::create("sink", Gst::PAD_SINK, Gst::PAD_ALWAYS,
                    Gst::Caps::create_from_string("video/x-raw, format=BGRA")));
    klass->add_pad_template(Gst::PadTemplate::create("src", Gst::PAD_SRC, Gst::PAD_ALWAYS,
                    Gst::Caps::create_from_string("video/x-raw, format=BGRA")));
    } 
    Glib::RefPtr<Gst::Pad> source;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gst::Buffer> wbuf;
  explicit DerivedFromBaseTransform(GstBaseTransform *gobj)
  : Glib::ObjectBase(typeid (DerivedFromBaseTransform)), // type must be registered before use
    Gst::BaseTransform(gobj) {
    set_passthrough(true);
        //set_in_place(true);
        source = get_static_pad("src");
  }
    Gst::FlowReturn transform_ip_vfunc(const Glib::RefPtr<Gst::Buffer> &buf) override {
        //cout << "Hello buffer" << endl;
        Gst::MapInfo mapinfo;
        wbuf = buf->create_writable();
        wbuf->map(mapinfo, Gst::MAP_WRITE);
        //cout << mapinfo.get_size() / 320 / 240 << endl;
        cv::Mat mat{240, 320, CV_8UC4, mapinfo.get_data()};
        cv::circle(mat, {100, 100}, 30, {0,0,255,255}, 3);
        source->push(move(wbuf));
        return Gst::FLOW_OK;
    }
  static bool register_element(Glib::RefPtr<Gst::Plugin> plugin) {
    return Gst::ElementFactory::register_element(plugin, "myfilter",
                10, Gst::register_mm_type<DerivedFromBaseTransform>("myfilter"));
  }
};

int main() {
    Gst::init();
  bool plugin_registered = Plugin::register_static(GST_VERSION_MAJOR, GST_VERSION_MINOR, 
            "derivedfrombasetransform", "exemplary element C++-derived from Gst::BaseTransform",
            sigc::ptr_fun(&DerivedFromBaseTransform::register_element), "0.123", "LGPL",
            "source?", "package?", "http://example.com");

  auto element = Gst::ElementFactory::create_element("myfilter");
    auto loop = Glib::MainLoop::create();
    auto pipe = Gst::Pipeline::create();
    auto queue1 = Gst::ElementFactory::create_element("queue2");
    auto queue2 = Gst::ElementFactory::create_element("queue2");
    auto src = Gst::ElementFactory::create_element("videotestsrc");
    auto out = Gst::ElementFactory::create_element("autovideosink");
    auto conv = Gst::ElementFactory::create_element("videoconvert");
    auto conv2 = Gst::ElementFactory::create_element("videoconvert");
    pipe->add(src)->add(element)->add(conv)->add(out)->add(conv2)->add(queue1)->add(queue2);
    src->link(conv)->link(queue1)->link(element)->link(queue2)->link(conv2)->link(out);

    pipe->set_state(Gst::STATE_PLAYING);
    loop->run();
    pipe->set_state(Gst::STATE_NULL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my transform function like this. It works now.

Oddly Gst::MAP_READ flag should be set.

Then no crash in writing to buffer.

```
Gst::FlowReturn transform_ip_vfunc(const Glib::RefPtr<Gst::Buffer> &buf) override {
    buf->map(mapinfo, Gst::MAP_READ);
    cv::Mat mat{720, 1280, CV_8UC4, mapinfo.get_data()};
    cv::circle(mat, {100, 100}, 30, {0, 0, 255, 255}, 3);
    buf->unmap(mapinfo);
    return Gst::FLOW_OK;
}
```